# Syntax error on boolean declaration

Tags: java, class, char

I have to keep it in the case 'A' Format i just don't understand what I should have in the (char c) because that seems to be where the error is coming from.  If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class PhoneNumber {


 private int areacode;
 private int number;    
 private int ext;    

 PhoneNumber() {

 areacode = 0;
 number = 0;
 ext = 0;

}

PhoneNumber(int newnumber) {

areacode = 216;

number = newnumber;
ext = 0;

}

PhoneNumber(int newarea, int newnumber, int newext) {

 areacode = newarea;
 number = newnumber;
 ext = newext;

}


PhoneNumber(String newnumber) {
String areacode = str[0];
String number = str[1];
String[] str = newnumber.split("-");
String[] number = newnumber;

boolean b1, b2;
int i = 0;
int place = 0;
for (int x: newnumber){
    newnumber.charAt[i] = place;
    b1 = Character.isDigit(place);
    if (b1 == true){
    number = place;
    i++;
}   else {
    b2 = Character.isLetter(place);
}   if (b2 == true) {
    number = decode(place);
    i++;
}   else {
    System.out.print("invalid phone number!");
}
}

 System.out.print(areacode.concat(number));
return newnumber;
}



private String decode(place) {

 switch (c) {    
    case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': return "2";
    case 'D': case 'E': case 'F': return "3";    
    case 'G': case 'H': case 'I': return "4";    
    case 'J': case 'K': case 'L': return "5";    
    case 'M': case 'N': case 'O': return "6";    
    case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S': return "7";    
    case 'T': case 'U': case 'V': return "8";    
    case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'z': return "9";    
    default: return "";    
  }

}


public boolean equals(PhoneNumber pn) {
    //not complete
}


public String toString() {
    //not complete
}



}
```

Here is the error:

```
G:\CIS260\Assignments>javac PhoneNumber.java
PhoneNumber.java:53: error: <identifier> expected
private String decode(place) {
                           ^
1 error
```

Comment: Boolean *what* equals b1 and b2? `boolean b0 = b1, b2` is a correct declaration; so is `boolean b1, b2`. `boolean = ...` is not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user should try following a tutorial first...

Comment: so your saying it should be boolean b1, b2 instead

Comment: if there is any other suggestions i would love to hear them

Comment: you really shouldn't radically change your question like this, i answered your question, accept the answer and move on to your next question in its own thread.

Comment: i dont know how to delete questions or else i would.  New to the site.  Sorry rpg711 I thought editing it would be the smartest move as well.  I deleted the boolean tags in order to make it its own thread sort of.  Sorry to disrespect the site

Comment: you shouldnt delete questions anyways, click the green checkmark for accepting answers and move on :)

Comment: nvm got it new to the site again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one error that jump out at me. Note that if you have a syntax error, most compilers will freak out and mark everything past the actual error as errors. The best way to debug accidental syntax errors is to look at the first error :)

```
boolean = b1, b2;
```

Makes no sense. a variable declaration is as follows

```
[Type] [Variable Name] | ,[Additional Vars];
```

so it should be `boolean b1, b2;`

```
private String decode(char c) {

 switch (c) {

    case 'A': case 'B': case 'C': return "2";

    case 'D': case 'E': case 'F': return "3";

    case 'G': case 'H': case 'I': return "4";

    case 'J': case 'K': case 'L': return "5";

    case 'M': case 'N': case 'O': return "6";

    case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S': return "7";

    case 'T': case 'U': case 'V': return "8";

    case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'z': return "9";

    default: return "";

    }

}
```

I suggest you use a lookup table(hashmap) to do this set of code, it looks much less ugly and is easier on sore eyes.

An example of that would be

```
private static final Map<Char, String> myDecodeLookup = new Hashmap<Char,String>();

static{ //initializer block
    myDecodeLookup.put('A', "2");
    myDecodeLookup.put('B', "2");
    //and so and and so forth
}

private String decode(char c) throws KeyNotFoundException{
   return MyClassName.myDecodeLookup.get(c); //you should code this to support the keynotfoundexception that this might throw, or not.
}
```

If you ever find yourself debugging a **syntax error** for 5 hours, you should probably take a step back and look up the syntax of the language constructs themselves... that's good advice to take going forward.

Comment: Java does support fall through cases in a switch statement, and in this simple example has some advantages over a Map.

Comment: @cistearns ah, fixed thanks, actually had no idea, well, learned something. based on what I know from other languages with switch-fallthrough though, it still is bad practice because it is much more difficult to read the behavior of a switch statement with unclear breaks.